# Customize Visual Studio Mac 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin, ide, visual-studio-mac

I would like to set Visual Studio for Mac 2017 to automatically open .axml files in the source editor mode without loading the Android designer.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

On top of that I would also like this to happen when I use the Go To File binding I have setup. Currently every time I open an .axml file through Go To File it takes about 10-50 seconds to load up (no exaggeration). If it takes longer than that it never opens and the entire IDE stops working.

I am currently right-clicking on the files and selecting open with -> Source Code Editor.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: A recommendation. use bootcamp, install windows and use VS2017, your life will be more easy and happy.

Comment: @Gusman I use parallels along with Visual Studio 2017 for some things (nuget upgrades, Web Api work, etc). Mostly I work in VS Mac when I'm deving on Xamarin. When I do work on it I'd like the above mentioned behaviour to exist.

Comment: Currently this does not seem to be possible without writing a custom extension. Whilst Visual Studio on Windows allows you to change the default editor, or add new external editors, Visual Studio for Mac does not have any feature to do this. Even if you could disable the Android layout view, which I do not think you can easily, the file would still open up in the text editor since that would be the default editor.

Comment: @MattWard yeah that's what I thought. Hopefully this functionality is added soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Visual Studio for Mac does not currently support configuring the editor used to open a file I created an [Open With addin](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-open-with-addin) that provides this feature.

It provides an Open With dialog that allows you to change the default editor or application used to open a file in a similar way to how this is done in Visual Studio on Windows.

After installing the Open With addin into Visual Studio for Mac 7.0 or above, you can right click a file in the Solution window, and select Open With - Preferences to display an Open With dialog. This dialog is based on Visual Studio's dialog. You can change the default application or editor used here or add a custom application.

So you should be able to configure Visual Studio to open .axml files into the text editor or Android Studio.

[More details can be found in this blog post](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2017/08/06/ConfiguringOpenWithInVisualStudioMac7-0/)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I'll check it out tomorrow and come back to accept the answer if it works. This is so awesome.

Comment: Perfect dude. Thank you so much for sharing this